# Replace values of a group with group aggregate in numpy/pandas

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have an image in a numpy array X:

```
array([[ 0.01176471,  0.49019608,  0.01568627],
       [ 0.01176471,  0.49019608,  0.01568627],
       [ 0.00784314,  0.49411765,  0.00784314],
       ..., 
       [ 0.03921569,  0.08235294,  0.10588235],
       [ 0.09411765,  0.14901961,  0.18431373],
       [ 0.10196078,  0.15294118,  0.21568627]])
```

I've ran a clusterizer algorithm over this array to find similar colors and have another array with classes for each pixel Y:

```
array([19, 19, 19, ..., 37, 20, 20], dtype=int32)
```

What are the fastest, prettiest, and most pythonistic ways to replace the color of all pixels in a cluster with the mean over that cluster?

I've came up with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
<...>
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(X, columns=list('rgb'))
df['cls'] = Y
mean_colors = df.groupby('cls').mean().values
# as suggested in comments below
# for cls in range(len(mean_colors)):
#    X[Y==cls] = mean_colors[cls]
X = mean_colors[Y]
```

Is there a way to do it only in pandas or only in numpy?

Comment: Assuming `Y` contains all the labels, how about a simple indexing `mean_colors[Y]`?

Comment: For your example your code isn't working, because you have in `Y` 3 different values and when are you comparing `Y==cls` nothing happen because there are not in the index... (cls only equals to 0, 1, 2)

Comment: @Divakar yep, that's beautiful, thank you!

Comment: @AntonProtopopov it works, i've tried. I don't have 3 values in Y, I have them in X.

Comment: @Direvius it's hard to answer without reproducing your result. You could reduce your `X` and `Y` and attach them with working code or produce [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Anyway I have that data from the original source it's just a advice for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all labels are present in `Y`, you can use [`basic-indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) -

```
mean_colors[Y]
```

For cases when indexing into the same location multiple times, for performance you can also use [`np.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) instead of pure indexing, like so -

```
np.take(mean_colors,Y,axis=0)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [107]: X = np.random.rand(10000,3)

In [108]: Y = np.random.randint(0,100,(10000))

In [109]: np.allclose(np.take(mean_colors,Y,axis=0),mean_colors[Y])
Out[109]: True           # Verify approaches

In [110]: %timeit mean_colors[Y]
1000 loops, best of 3: 280 µs per loop

In [111]: %timeit np.take(mean_colors,Y,axis=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.7 µs per loop
```

Comment: On my machine, with my data:
pure indexing is 6.13 ms, take is 2.08 ms and `df.groupby('cls').transform(np.mean).values` is 65.2 ms.

I think these two are the best =)

Comment: ah, I didn't consider that i need to find the mean_colors before

Comment: pure indexing: 610 ms; 
take indexing: 604 ms; 
pandas transform: 659 ms

Answer (score 1):

You could use `transform` for groupby object and then assign `.values` result to your `X` :

```
X = df.groupby('cls').transform(np.mean).values
```

Information about `tranfrom` from `help`:

> ```
> transform(func, *args, **kwargs) method of pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy instance
>     Call function producing a like-indexed DataFrame on each group and
>     return a DataFrame having the same indexes as the original object
>     filled with the transformed values
>
>     Parameters
>     ----------
>     f : function
>         Function to apply to each subframe
>
>     Notes
>     -----
>     Each subframe is endowed the attribute 'name' in case you need to know
>     which group you are working on.
>
>     Examples
>     --------
>     >>> grouped = df.groupby(lambda x: mapping[x])
>     >>> grouped.transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())
> ```